# Boxplots in Matplotlib: fill markers in the boxes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to fill markers inside boxes as the following boxplot image.

I don't have idea how to implement this.  I searched for it on the web. There are posts about filling colours in the boxes (http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo2.html) but it seems there are no posts about filling markers.

[image: Boxplot]

Comment: Please post the code to generate your figure here.  Links rot and it make is easier to read/understand your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be relatively simple. I took the [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo2.html) and added one line (`set_hatch`) immediately after the creation of the polygon:

```
...
boxPolygon = Polygon(boxCoords, facecolor=boxColors[k])
boxPolygon.set_hatch('*')
ax1.add_patch(boxPolygon)
...
```

and removed the sample marker plot command. This is what I got:

[image]

For more information on `patch.set_hatch`, see [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hatch_demo.html).